# Finding a set of values

Tags: python

I have a curve_hex generator, it uses two coordinates, I'm looking for only one coordinate. The script searches for one coordinate value easily, but if I specify several coordinates for the search, then it does not find anything.

```
wanted='58611774815559422402170859520215717661755632997646071327165159211728464937238'
curve_hex='(58611774815559422402170859520215717661755632997646071327165159211728464937238, 108722706890170119196943746054760504186165603293283329661416022207913727808252)'
if str(curve_hex).find(wanted)!=-1:
   print (curve_hex[str(curve_hex).find(wanted):str(curve_hex).find(wanted)+len(wanted)])
else:
    print ('not')
```

One value is found normally. But if I add several values, the script writes an error

```
wanted='58611774815559422402170859520215717661755632997646071327165159211728464937238', '108722706890170119196943746054760504186165603293283329661416022207913727808252'
curve_hex='(58611774815559422402170859520215717661755632997646071327165159211728464937238, 108722706890170119196943746054760504186165603293283329661416022207913727808252)'
if str(curve_hex).find(wanted)!=-1:
   print (curve_hex[str(curve_hex).find(wanted):str(curve_hex).find(wanted)+len(wanted)])
else:
    print ('not')
```

Tell me how to do it right. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the second case, `wanted` does not look like one value... don't you need to loop over the list?` Try `print(wanted)` before your test, just to be sure

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, if you are happy with your if else conditions, and your only problem is that you can’t add multiple values to wanted. I would convert wanted to a list that includes all your wanted values, and loop over those.

Something like this:

```
wanted = ['586..{copy the whole value here}', '108...{copy the value here}']
curve_hex='(58611774815559422402170859520215717661755632997646071327165159211728464937238, 108722706890170119196943746054760504186165603293283329661416022207913727808252)'
for value in wanted:
    if str(curve_hex).find(value)!=-1:
       print (curve_hex[str(curve_hex).find(value):str(curve_hex).find(value)+len(value)])
    else:
        print ('not')
```

Comment: @Константин please let me know in a comment if this is what you are looking for and if it has helped you

Comment: Thank you, your method works. But when I added it to the working script, where the constant generation is going on, the search stopped working like the recording

Comment: Your solution doesn't work if the script uses while True:

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding some basic concepts:

Definitions like this result in different types

```py
    wanted='58611774815559422402170859520215717661755632997646071327165159211728464937238' 
    type(wanted) # string

    wanted='58611774815559422402170859520215717661755632997646071327165159211728464937238', '108722706890170119196943746054760504186165603293283329661416022207913727808252'
    type(wanted) # tuple

    curve_hex='(58611774815559422402170859520215717661755632997646071327165159211728464937238, 108722706890170119196943746054760504186165603293283329661416022207913727808252)'
    type(wanted) # string
```

So you should choose a type first. Tuple is the best case.

```
    wanted=('58611774815559422402170859520215717661755632997646071327165159211728464937238', '108722706890170119196943746054760504186165603293283329661416022207913727808252')
    curve_hex=('58611774815559422402170859520215717661755632997646071327165159211728464937238', '108722706890170119196943746054760504186165603293283329661416022207913727808252')
    for i in wanted:
        for x,j in enumerate(curve_hex):
            if i in j:
                print(f'{i} in {curve_hex} at position {x}')
```